# How does android define max heap size for an application?

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how android defines the max heap size for an application?
I am getting this:

> W/dalvikvm( 2306): 58503184 byte allocation exceeds the 50331648 byte maximum heap size

I would like to know how/where android defines the max heap size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It varies from device to device.

You can get the approximate per-application memory class of a device by running [getMemoryClass()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29)